# in printing singly linked list, at the end of execution of c program, it shows file has stopped working

Tags: c

I created a Singly Linked List and wrote a method to print it. It has compiled properly and ran,but at the end of execution, it shows list.exe(file generated after compilation of code) has stopped working and windows is checking for solution as shown below.

[image]

list.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct List
{
    int a;
    List *b;
};

void PrintElement(List *);

int main()
{
    List *head,*temp;
    int n,k;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        temp->b=(List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
        if(i==0)
        {
            temp=(List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
            head=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp=temp->b;
        }
        scanf("%d",&temp->a);


    }
    temp->b='\0';
    PrintElement(head);
    return(0);
}

void PrintElement(List *head)
{
    List *temp1=head;
    do
    {

    printf("%d\n",temp1->a);
    temp1=temp1->b;
   }
   while(temp1!='\0');
   free(temp1);
}
```

Can anybody explain what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you `free(temp1)` at the end of your `PrintElement` function (which should be called `PrintList`) ?

Comment: 'Can anybody explain what i am doing wrong?' - not debugging before posting here.

Comment: Do not post screenshots. Paste text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *undefined behavior*, because of this line

```
temp->b=(List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
```

At this point you haven't initialized `temp` yet, you do it a couple of lines down.

You also never initialize the "next" pointer `b` to `NULL` anywhere, so when you traverse the list you will go outside of the list leading once again to undefined behavior. And to add insult to injury, you then attempt to `free` the node that you got by walking beyond the end of the list. As well as *only* freeing that memory, and not the actual nodes you allocate.

Also, there is a distinct different between the null-character that marks the end of strings, and a null-pointer. Most compilers will evaluate both `'\0'` and `NULL` to the same actual value, but they are still distinct semantic entities.